# How is migration of test case done in Test Lab and Manager - VSTS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How is migration of test case done using the Excel or Other 3rd party applications in Test Lab and Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/